# How to import a dictionary of questions from another python file and print them randomly for a quiz?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've made a dictionary of questions and I need to import them and ask them randomly in a quiz that I'm making.

```
history_data= [

    {
        "question":"What year did Adolf Hitler die?",
        "choices":{"a": "1940", "b": "1946", "c": "1943", "d": "1945"},
        "answer": "d"
    },
    {
        "question":"Who was the monarch of England in 1509?",
        "choices":{"a": "James I", "b": "Henry VIII", "c": "Queen Victoria I", "d": "James II"},
        "answer": "b"
    },
    {
        "question":"Which British doctor was the pioneer of the smallpox vaccine?",
        "choices":{"a": "Marie Curie", "b": "Alexander Fleming", "c": "Louis Pasteur", "d": "Edward Jenner"},
        "answer": "d"
    },
    {
        "question":"Which century did Queen Elizabeth I rule in?",
        "choices":{"a": "16th", "b": "14th", "c": "17th", "d": "15th"},
        "answer": "a"
    },
    {
        "question":"Who was the Soviet Union Leader during World War II?",
        "choices":{"a": "Vladimir Lenin", "b": "Nikita Khrushchev", "c": "Joseph Stalin", "d": "Karl Marx"},
        "answer": "c"
    }
]
```

This is stored in historyDict.py and I have another file named Code.py which includes the sign up and login. There is also a music dictionary as I have a choice of 2 quizzes for the student.

Code.py:

```
from musicDict import music_data
from historyDict import history_data
import random

def quiz():
    sChoice=['1','2']
    unknownSubject=True
    while unknownSubject:
        subject=input("\n1)Music\n2)History\n\nPlease choose a subject number (1 or 2): ")
        if subject not in sChoice:
            print("Sorry, that was not an option.\n")
        else:
            break
    #When the same format is shown, it can be confusing so a delay can separate them   
    dChoice=['1','2','3']
    unknownDifficulty=True
    while unknownDifficulty:
        difficulty=input("\n1)Easy\n2)Medium\n3)Hard\n\nPlease choose a difficulty number (1,2 or 3): ")
        if difficulty not in dChoice:
            print("Sorry, that was not an option.\n")
        else:
            break
    if subject==("1"):
        print('\n')
        q=random.choice(music_data)
        print(q.get('question'))
        answer=input(q.get('choices')).lower()

        if answer == q.get('answer'):
            print("Correct!\n")
        else:
            print("Wrong answer!")

    if subject==("2"):
        print('\n')
        q=random.choice(history_data)
        print(q.get('question'))
        answer=input(q.get('choices')).lower()

        if answer == q.get('answer'):
            print("Correct!\n")
        else:
            print("Wrong answer!")
```

Comment: Use `myDict.quiz_data`

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. Where would I input this?

Comment: @GarbageCollector

Comment: In this line: `q=random.choice(quiz_data)`

Comment: Thanks, I used your code and updated it above. Could you please take a look and tell me how to print the answers in order? Right now it shows the options in random order. @GarbageCollector

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `quiz_data` from the package `myDict` into the current namespace:

```
from myDict import quiz_data
```

Comment: @Navid glad to help!

Comment: One problem. The answers are shown in a random order. For example: Which century did Queen Elizabeth I rule in? {'c': '17th', 'b': '14th', 'a': '16th', 'd': '15th'} @Ajax1234

Answer (score 0):

Import the `quiz_data` from `myDict`:

```
from myDict import quiz_data
```

Dictionaries are inherently unorded, so there might be some screw-ups. If you want to sort the dicts in order, then use lists or tuples instead.

Comment: I tried this but the answers are printed in a random order which I'm trying to fix. Do you know how I'd go about that? @KennyChau

Comment: I've updated the code in the main post so you can see. A few of the names have been changed but they're very similar.

Comment: Where is the `subject` variable defined?

Comment: I've updated the code to show my entire function. I also have a music quiz which is the exact same. I just need to find a way to list the answer choices in order.